# Error "Method isEmpty in android.text.TextUtils not mocked" when using PowerMockito.spy

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I use Mockito and PowerMock for local Unit tests in my Android app:

```
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.8.9'

String powerMockVersion = "1.7.3"
testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:${powerMockVersion}"
testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:${powerMockVersion}"
```

Here is my code:

**MyTextUtils.java**

```
package sample.com.sample_app;

import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.text.TextUtils;

public class MyTextUtils {

    private MyTextUtils() {
        throw new AssertionError();
    }

    public static boolean isEmpty(@Nullable final CharSequence cs) {
        return TextUtils.isEmpty(cs);
    }
}
```

**SystemUtils.java**

```
package sample.com.sample_app;

import java.util.Random;

public class SystemUtils {

    private SystemUtils() {
        throw new AssertionError();
    }

    public static long currentTimeMillis() {
        return System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public static long nextLong() {
        return new Random().nextLong();
    }
}
```

And my tests.

**FooTest.java**

```
package sample.com.sample_app;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(SystemUtils.class)
public class FooTest {

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        PowerMockito.spy(SystemUtils.class);
        PowerMockito.when(SystemUtils.currentTimeMillis()).thenReturn(1_000L);
    }

    @Test
    public void foo() {
        assertEquals(1_000L, SystemUtils.currentTimeMillis());
    }
}
```

**LoremIpsumTest.java**

```
package sample.com.sample_app;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(MyTextUtils.class)
public class LoremIpsumTest {

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        PowerMockito.spy(MyTextUtils.class);
        PowerMockito.when(MyTextUtils.isEmpty("")).thenReturn(true);
    }

    @Test
    public void lorem() {
        assertTrue(MyTextUtils.isEmpty(""));
    }
}
```

When I run `LoremIpsumTest`, it fails with the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method isEmpty in android.text.TextUtils not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details.
```

If I replace `PowerMockito.spy(MyTextUtils.class);` with `PowerMockito.mockStatic(MyTextUtils.class);`, `LoremIpsumTest` works.

On the other hand, `FooTest` works with `PowerMockito.spy(SystemUtils.class);`. What's wrong with the partial mocking thing in `LoremIpsumTest`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support#TOC-Method-...-not-mocked.-

"We are aware that the default behavior is problematic when using classes like Log or TextUtils and will evaluate possible solutions in future releases."

https://medium.com/@okmanideep/dont-create-that-stringutils-to-unit-test-your-android-class-8ab32af34e84